# Linux sed command: replace string1 with string2 but only when string1 is not at the end of the line

Tags: string, sed, line, substitution

I have Html file with line breaks 
 and space characters

I would like to replace the line breaks br/ with spaces #160; but only when

 strings are in the middle of the line, not at the end of the line (re-wrapping
the paragraphs, the output was from pdftohtml command line).

In another words, use sed to replace s1 with s2 when s1 is not at end-of-line.

Suggestions? I am trying to google/solve it myself, but maybe you guys know the answer

Comment: We are not here to suggest tools/code, but to help in case you provide searches/experimentations/tests and having issue with **existing code**, even failed attempts

Comment: You can try using a regex. To ensure that br is not at the end require that there is at least one character after it. Something like `sed -e s|<br/>.| |`. Note using | as separation token to avoid escaping

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to match `s1` followed by any character, and replace it by `s2` followed by this matched character.

```
% echo 's1foos1bars1bazs1' | sed 's/s1\(.\)/s2\1/g'
s2foos2bars2bazs1
```